# Ways to test if my app is making the correct amount of api calls

Tags: http, frontend, cypress

I'm testing a react app with cypress, and cypress is really good at checking if atleast n many are calls are made on load, and not so good at checking if only those calls were made. The app itself is a pretty standard react app that uses window.fetch  for api calls. Is there another service, like cypress something similar, that's got the ability to test that in an automated fashion?

For instance, if you visit the site logged in we have three config calls. If a developer commits code that accidentally calls one of those twice, ideally I'd like an automated test to catch that.

I don't want to do it in Cypress because it seems like that's not what the product is really intended to do unless you hack it with an undocumented solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need a hard wait to ensure you check after all calls have been issued.

Also recommend stubbing so that there's no latency waiting for server response.

```js
it('check for excess calls', () => {

  cy.intercept('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {}).as('fetch')

  cy.visit('/').then(() => {

    // wait for expected calls
    cy.wait('@fetch')
    cy.wait('@fetch')
    cy.wait('@fetch')

    cy.wait(500)             
    cy.get('@fetch.all')     // check the call count
      .should(calls => {
        expect(calls).to.have.length(3)  // no extra calls
      })
  })
})
```

Tested with this app HTML

```html
<script>
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
</script>
```

You may want to burn-test to get the right wait time, see [Burning Tests with cypress-grep](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/burning-tests/)

---

Alternatively you can wait four times and catch the error

```js
it('check for excess calls', () => {
  cy.intercept('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {}).as('fetch')
  cy.visit('html/call-limit.html').then(() => {

    cy.wait('@fetch')
    cy.wait('@fetch')
    cy.wait('@fetch')

    Cypress.once('fail', (error) => {
      // catch ignore failure on 4th cy.wait('@fetch')
      if (error.message.includes('No request ever occurred')) { 
        return
      }
      throw error  // rethrow to fail for another reason
    })
    cy.wait('@fetch')  // should fail and trigger listener above

    cy.get('@fetch.all')
      .should(calls => {
        expect(calls).to.have.length(3)
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but I'm already waiting and checking for the calls I know are going to happen. What I want to do is test for extra calls happening that the may not be intended, for instance in that first example, if fetch was called a fourth time when I wasn't expecting it

Comment: You're missing the extra step - either wait a time after and check the call count, or explicitly wait for the first "extra" call and catch the error if it does not occur.

Comment: That's the undocumented solution, .all, I didn't want to rely on.

Comment: Both ways work, I've tested them. Response time for 4th request will not be predictable, how else do you expect to handle it?